# Erro ao gerar relatorio PDF com mpdf60

Tags: php, mpdf

Já faz alguns dias que estou tentando gerar um relatório PDF com PHP, encontrei vários exemplos na internet e todos dá o mesmo erro, abaixo coloquei o código do exemplo e o print do erro.

Meu servidor Xampp, está usando a versão 7 do PHP e a biblioteca para gerar o PDF é mpdf60.

```
<?php 
 include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");

 $html = "
 <fieldset>
 <h1>Teste de relatório</h1>
 <div class='creditos'>
 <p>Relatório pdf</p>
 </div>
 ";

 $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
 $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// $css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $mpdf->Output();

 exit;

 ?>
```

Veja a saída de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Várias bibliotecas geram esse erro. Se alguém puder sugerir outra opção. Meu projeto é simples não utiliza framework nenhum.

Comment: Muito obrigado Everson por editar minha pergunta, melhorou muito. Mas e quanto a minha dúvida, você pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por que você comentou a atribuição na variável $css?

Comment: Comentei para ver se era isso que estava gerando algum erro. Você matou a charada, era isso que esta gerando o erro. Muito obrigado

Comment: Se o erro parou de aparecer , marque como respondida sua pergunta , para que facilite a busca da solução de outros que estejam com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retire o comentário da variável $css

```
 $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
 $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 $css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
 $mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certo